# What did St. Theresa of Àvila mean by the "Prayer of Recollection"?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, saint

From [*The Way of Perfection*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6370), chapter 28

> It is a prayer that brings with it many blessings. **This prayer is called "recollection,"** because the soul collects its faculties together and enters within itself to be with its God. And its divine Master comes more quickly to teach it... those who by such a method can enclose themselves within this little Heaven of our soul, where the Maker of Heaven and Earth is present, and grow accustomed to refusing to be where the exterior senses in their distraction have gone or look in that direction should believe they are following an excellent path and that they will not fail to drink water from the fount; for they will journey far in a short time.

The bolded part is the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1):

St. Teresa explains it very well, but see Juan G. Arintero, O.P., [*Mystical Evolution*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=5897) ch. 4:

> [Prayer of recollection is] an [infused](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34205) type of prayer and is far superior to the prayer which is [acquired](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31624) by our own efforts and diligence. Human industry is powerless to attain it; God gives it when He wishes and as He wishes. Yet we should not on that account refrain from disposing ourselves to receive it and we should not harden our hearts when privileged to hear the divine invitation. For the soul makes more progress and is more illumined during a single moment of that type of prayer than during entire years spent in profound and prolonged considerations.